# Lucene downgrade 3.6.0 to 3.5.0

Tags: search, lucene, faceted-search, downgrade

We are using Lucene version 3.6.0 in our project. Now we decided to start using Bobo Browse for faceted search. However the current version of Bobo Browse (3.1.0) doesn't support Lucene 3.6.0, therefore we decided to downgrade back to version 3.5.0. I was reading the changelog but I couldn't find any mention of changes in the index structure. Does anyone know if it will be necessary to rebuild the index? This is something we want to avoid. Many thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, we managed to downgrade Lucene from 3.6.0 to 3.5.0 without rebuilding the index. I simply replaced the libraries and everything worked.