# Lucene -- filter documents with specific field

Tags: java, search, lucene

With regard to my previous question ([Lucene downgrade 3.6.0 to 3.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284384/lucene-downgrade-3-6-0-to-3-5-0)) I was wondering how could I filter out those documents (in Lucene 3.5.0) that have or don't have specific field (regardless the contents of the field). In Lucene 3.6.0 there is a [FieldValueFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldValueFilter.html) class that can be used to do this. Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710089/find-all-lucene-documents-having-a-certain-field) but I'm not sure how could I accomplish the same thing using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found the solution myself. I used [TermRangeFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeFilter.html). The field I was working with contained IDs (stored as strings), so I used the following filter:

```
Filter filter = new TermRangeFilter("field", "0", null, true, false);
```

The same thing can be achieved also with this shorted code:

```
Filter filter = TermRangeFilter.More("filter", "0");
```

This solution seems to work. I hope this will help someone!

Comment: If you want all values, then why limit by "0"? you could use: Filter filter = new TermRangeFilter("field", null, null, false, false);
Which translates into: field:{* TO *}